# Current in a circuit with resistors and capacitors

Tags: electric-circuits

Suppose we have a circuit with both resistors and capacitors and some voltage source. If we want to calculate the current in the circuit, do we apply Ohms law?

My doubt is that this would only take into consideration the resistors and not the capacitors, so do the capacitors play any role in the current flowing through the circuit?

Comment: It would depend on whether you have a steady state or a changing current. In a steady state, you can ignore the capacitors. Otherwise, you would need to use an extension to Ohms law to account for the reactance of the capacitors.

Comment: I agree with LDC3, with the clarification that "ignore the capacitors" means treat them as having infinite resistance (i.e., a break in the circuit).

Answer (score 1):

Ohm's law won't get you very far when dealing with RC circuits (R=resistor, C=capacitors).

The general way to deal with such circuits, as described in the [WP page on RC circuits,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit) is to use [Kirchhoff's circuit laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) to write down a differential equation. Solving the differential equation will give you $I(t)$.

The basic idea to applying the appropriate Kirchhoff's rule is that you are adding up the potential drops across all element. You already know the voltage drop across a resistor ($V=IR$). There are other formulae for other elements, like $V=Q/C$ for capacitors. Combining these drops carefully gives you the differential equation you need.

Comment: Whoa whoa V=I*R, not I/R